# Issues with uploading file to google drive via google apps script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm in the process of writing a program in google apps script that will allow users to upload files onto google drive. However, when I run the program, google.script.run does not run the function to upload a file (secFunc(formObject)). Because the program is run asynchronous, I'm having difficulties debugging or troubleshooting my issue. I believe the issue is a typo or bad method within secFunc, but given that I was able to run this function with no issue a week ago, I'm struggling to understand what the issue is.
JS-

```
function uploadFiles(){
  const htmlDlg = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index').setWidth(350).setHeight(425);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlDlg, 'Email Attachments')
}

function secFunc(formObject){
  const blob = getBlob(formObject.myFile)
  DriveApp.createFile(blob)
}
```

Index.html-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="submitFunc(this)">
           <div class="form-group">
            <label for="myFile">Upload File</label> 
            <input name="myFile" class="myFile" type="file" id="myFile" />
           </div>
          <br>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <br>
        <div id="output"></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    function submitFunc(formObject){
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).secFunc(formObject)
    }
    function onSuccess() {
      var Output = 'Input Succesfully Translated';
      alert(Output)
      google.script.host.close()
    }
  </script> 
</html>
```

Expecting that, once uploadFiles() is triggered, an html popup will appear allowing user to input a file. Upon clicking the Submit button, the dialogue would close and the file would be uploaded to Drive. Currently, clicking the submit button gives no response.